# Function to keyframe any custom property; curve created but animation ignored

Tags: custom-properties

The original question was in fact ridiculous, a very basic syntax mistake. I corrected the error. But something more interesting occurred :
Although the animation curve is created, it is ignored and the custom property remains constant.
But :
If I move a keyframe in the curve editor, if I close Blender and reopen the file,  if I delete the keyframes and undo, then the animation works.
This is strange and inconvenient.

**Context :**

I need to **animate a set of custom properties** for a bunch of objets.

I found convenient to create a function to do it.

**Here it is :**

```
def KeyframeCustomProp ( obj , propName , value , time ):  
          
    string = "[\"" + propName + "\"]"
    obj[propName] = value
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path=string, frame = time)
```

I test the following calls :

```
KeyframeCustomProp(cube,"prop", 0.0,  10)  
KeyframeCustomProp(cube,"prop", 1.0,  45)
```

**My use :**
I have a big collection of instances. I need to animate the material(s) individually.
The material of the instanced object uses the attribute node to get the value of a custom property set on each instance.
It works ... I just need to animate these custom properties. The function lets me do it ... and with multiple custom properties if needed. ( although the curve created is ignored )

The material of the object ( generating the instances ) uses the attribute node :

[image]

Here is a simplified example with 2 instances. The first one gets its material animated independently from the other :

[image]

To reproduce the problem, delete the keyframes and run the script, you'll see that the "prop" custom property remains constant ... untill I do one of the inconvenient things mentioned earlier.

T H A N K S

Comment: instead of escaping double quotes, just use single quotes either for your string or for the string inside, plus use formatted strings to easily embed variables: `obj.keyframe_insert(data_path=f"['{propName}']", frame=time)`

Comment: Thank you Markus ... that's much more elegant.

Comment: Although I get "TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "['prop']" not found" if I replace just this line in my file ... which does not make no sens for me.

Comment: I just checked, apparently I was wrong, and single quotes inside don't work, so you need `obj.keyframe_insert(data_path=f'["{propName}"]', frame=time)` (tested this line)

Comment: No error. Cool. But something weird happens : I see the curve of the animated Custom Property, but its value is ignored in the material and it does not change in the Object Property tab. Insane.

Comment: If I move a keyframe in the curve editor, the changes are ... validated, and then it works ...

Comment: If I close Blender and reopen the file, the curve is also taken into account (using Blender 3.4 ) ... Isn't this a little bug ?

Comment: Same thing if I delete the keyframes and the undo. The curve is effective. Note the same thing occurs in your version and in mine ...

Comment: I think there's a need to "refresh" Blender when you made changes in animation via Python. At least I remember having similar issues, and doing some operations that update the viewport seemed to fix it. In my [Convert Rotation Mode addon](https://github.com/L0Lock/convertRotationMode/blob/main/convert_Rotation_Mode.py#L200), I change the current active frame, partially for that purpose if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thank you L0Lock, but my scripts changing or creating an animation via Python did not need this. Here, the problem began when I animated a Custom Property.
BTW, alas, changing active frame did not wake Blender up.